# requests.post() returns the search page, not the results page

Tags: python, post, python-requests, url-parameters

What I am trying to do is go onto https://www.ssrn.com/index.cfm/en/, search for an author name, and then click on that author's name to take me to the author page. Right now, I am stuck on that first step, as requests.post() just returns the original URL input, not the results page. I've searched around for a while but I have no idea what the problem is; if I've misidentified the key or something else.

Here is my code:

```
url = "https://www.ssrn.com/index.cfm/en/"

header = {}
header['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
obj = requests.post(url, headers = header, data = {'txtKey_Words': 'auth_name'}) # make POST request for each name
print(obj.url)
```

So `print(obj.url)` just returns https://www.ssrn.com/index.cfm/en/ instead of https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/results.cfm

Much appreciated!

Edit: Using https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/results.cfm returns https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/displayabstractsearch.cfm

Comment: Search form url is not the same as search url. Check source of the page and you'll find that `<form action="https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/results.cfm" ...>` - there's your post url

Comment: I had tried that initially but that returns <https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/displayabstractsearch.cfm> which is another search page.

Comment: And what about contents, not url? And what if you use that search page?

Comment: That url returns itself as well. And can you clarify what you mean by contents? I thought I might be missing some parameter but I'm not quite sure what parameters I could even be missing.

Comment: `obj.content`, obviously. Or rather `obj.text` for unicode string result. (Beware, it's going to be html page) Request gets the result directly, not via some url. Unique urls are used for data POSTed to change some state on the server, so server remembers it. In this case, no, you only search

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying about the URLs. But obj.text returns the same search webpage as well.